# Existence and algorithms for finding the composition inverse of a polynomial over a field?

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $f \in F_p[x] / q(x)$. I'm looking for algorithms to find the inverse $g$ and wondering does it exist under all conditions?

When can we find a $g(x) \in F_p[x]/q(x)$ so that $f(g(x)) =x$?

If feel like this is something that can be solved with grobner bases?

I'm not looking for a regular inverse, I'm looking for the composition inverse.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon , No I'm specifically asking about composition.

Comment: If $f$ has degree $\geq2$ and $\deg(g)>0$, then $\deg(f\circ g)\geq2\deg(g)>1=\deg(x)$. If $\deg(g)=0$, then $\deg(f\circ g)=0<1=\deg(x)$. If $\deg(f)=1$, then $f(x)=ax+b$ has inverse $g(x)=a^{-1}x+a^{-1}b$. So, you need the inverse of $a$, which you can find using Euclid's algorithm to get $r,s$ such that $ra+sp=1$ (this $p$ is the subscript one. You have two things denoted $p$ in the question).

Comment: @NDB, a two polynomials of different degree can be equal as functions.

Comment: The notation $f\in F_p[x]/p(x)$ is rather confusing. I'm assuming the first $p$ is a prime number and the second $p$ is an irreducible polynomial, so that $F_p[x]/p(x)$ denotes a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. Is this right? Then do you want to take $f(x)$ to be a polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_q$, i.e. an element of $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$? Or do you actually want to consider $f$ and $g$ to be  equivalence classes of polynomials in $F_p[x]$ modulo the ideal $(p(x))$? I don't think composition is well-defined for such equivalence classes...

Comment: Fixed the notation, $f \in F_q$, a finite field which may be written as $F_q = F_p / h(x)$ for some $h$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson As you perfectly know, that is not what $=$ means for polynomials. Address the OP about that, not me, when the question is not property formulated.

Comment: @NDB, I addressed you because you posted an argument which was based on two polynomials being different if their degrees were different. OP is asking about functional composition and a functional inverse, which suggests to me that OP might be interested in these polynomials as functions. It would be nice if OP were to clarify.

Comment: Question simulposted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452416/taking-polynomial-inverses-over-a-field without notice to either site, in violation of rules on both sites.